# why should we migrate to ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4

We have been trying to migrate to ionic 4 from ionic 3 for more than one month and still, it is not done completely. So made us question the decision we took and was wondering if there was anything that ionic 4 does better than ionic 3, apart from it is a faster argument?

I will mention some of the problems we encountered. Firstly there are not many posts about the migration. You mostly only find the posts of Josh Morony who tries to convince you that ionic 4 is wonderful and it is very easy to migrate. 
I am directly quoting from him: "I would estimate for most people it would take on average anywhere from 1 hour to 8 hours to upgrade most applications."
1 hour for the whole migration? even reading the migration documents takes half the day. Either he never had his hands on anything more complicated than a calculator and thinks every application is like that or he purposely deceives people.

I will just mention a tiny amount of the things we had to go through in the last weeks.

- Newly introduced Shadow Dom breaks almost every css you previously had, that and changed classes of the components
- SASS variables do not work, you have to migrate everything to CSS4 variables but they only seem to work half of the time. For example, in some cases, you use background css tag but in other cases, you have to use --background variable.
- Even the submit button doesn't work when you press enter key.
- Fab labels is broken, you have to implement them in a completely different way.
- You will probably see thousands of errors when you first compile after the migration but errors invisible is the real pain.
- There is sth wrong with service workers. They should be optional according to documentation but the application wasn't working without them. Previous codes you might have for service workers will be broken that is one thing I can say for certain.

Comment: We had some problems upgrading to Ionic 4 too, but these were fixed by going through the release docs (found here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases). There are some breaking changes documented. Maybe something you overlooked? Anyway flagged your question for being too broad. There is no specific answer that will fix your problems. Maybe separate them into small, resolvable pieces ...

Comment: @TomasVancoillie I am asking what is the advantage in ionic 4 compared to ionic 3 with all the caveats I listed before. I am not asking for solutions to my problems. The things I wrote about, I already solved somehow, that is how I know they are broken.

Comment: @TomasVancoillie If I saw a post like this before we started migrating, we wouldn't migrate at all since we have a very small team. Btw those breaking changes documentation doesnt list the things I wrote above.

Comment: hey, yes the migration is tough. I just finished mine for quite a large and complex app. Here is the article i wrote: https://link.medium.com/GoFG7gbdOX What helped me a LOT is that i prepared and rewrote a lot of my code while in v3 (sort of refactored the code to allow for less changes). Agree that css and template changes were the worst surprises but the result was worth it (see article), beyond performance.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko Thanks for the great post, it is more helpful to me than anything I read from Josh Morony so far.